# Send to context menu and merge using batch file

Tags: windows, batch-file, scripting, command

I am trying to select some files from a folder and right click "Send to" A batchfile.bat
I want to merge them using "copy /b" command. I scripted as follows.

here the problem is, it will work only if know the number of files which we are going to select. in below script it will work if i select 3 files from any folder.

what is the best way to merge the files i select and "send to" a batch file?

```
echo off
set file1=%1
set file2=%2
set file3=%3
copy /B %file1%+%file2%+%file3%  merged.txt
```

[image: Batch file already attached to menu]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace spaces with a plus sign. You'll need to test it.

```
set filepath=%*
set file=%filepath:" "="+"%
copy %file% newfile
```

Comment: It is working only if there is a space in full path (Eg :  D:\Test folder)
And it will give error if there is no space in the path (Eg : D:\Testfolder"

Answer (score 1):

This should work for text files: if the combined length of all path\filenames is less than around `8 KB`.

```
echo off
for %%a in (%*) do type "%%~a">>merged.txt
```

Comment: This is not just for text files there are some .vob files too